# Android: Como atualizar título e itens do ActionBar e DrawerLayout em tempo de execução?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment

Necessito atualizar o título do ActionBar e cada um dos itens do Drawer menu com a troca de idioma em tempo de execução.
Utilizo o seguinte código para alterar o idioma do meu aplicativo porém não consigo alterar título e itens do actionbar (seus nomes).
Já tentei usar o `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` e não funcionou. Estou usando a Support Library.
Os demais itens são atualizados somente o `Actionbar` e `Drawer` que não.

```
Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(getId());
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
fragTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
fragTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Poderia incluir o layout para o seu menu drawer e o layout da activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou chutar que você usa o `DrawerLayout` da Support Library v4 e o `ActionBar` da Support Library v7, mas tenho duas sugestões para resolver esse problema:

Modo simples: reiniciar a `Activity`, acreditando que as `Strings` que você usa no `Drawer` e no `ActionBar` virão corretas logo depois, isso pode ser feito da seguinte maneira:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
        Intent intent = activity.getIntent();
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

        activity.finish();
        activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        activity.recreate();
    }
```

Esse modo é o mais fácil, porém há o risco de perda de dados e tem todo o overhead de recriar a activity.

A outra forma, talvez melhor dependendo do caso é recuperar o `ListView` do `DrawerLayout` e usar o método `notifyDataSetChanged` ou `notifyDataSetInvalidated` no `Adapter`, forçando a atualização dos itens do menu. E com relação ao `ActionBar`, é só atualizar o `title`.

O ActionBar pode ser atualizado dessa maneira:

```
ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();

ab.setTitle(...); // Setar o title novamente, com a lingua correta.
```

Já o `Drawer`, você precisa guardar uma referência na sua Activity ou recuperá-lo do `ListView`, sendo dessa forma:

```
// Se ja tiver a referência, não precisa fazer isso..
ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.drawer_list); // resId do ListView
ListAdapter adapter = lv.getAdapter();

adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidate();
// ou dependendo da necessidade
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Amigo muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente!